# DirectDraw Surface - data layout

Tags: opengl, textures, dds-format

Opengl texture coordinate [0,0] is located in a lower left corner. Does DDS file contain informations about a data layout (if data begin in top left or bottom left corner) or there is one fixed layout ? For example ktx file contains such information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DDS file format does not contain information about where the origin is. Since DDS is a DirectX format, it will usually be stored with a top-left origin, but there is no guarantee for that.

You can check out which information is stored in a dds file by checking the [Microsoft Docs: Programming Guide for DDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddds/dx-graphics-dds-pguide), especially the [DDS_HEADER struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddds/dds-header)